# Jenkinsfile stage not failing despite step failling

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

```
stage('python') {
  sh script: '''
    #!/bin/bash
    set -ex

    python2.7 -u run_test.py                     <--- this script had a import error but stage passed


  '''.stripIndent()
}
```

In the log,

```
[2021-01-09T05:35:25.812Z] + python2.7 -u run_test.py
[2021-01-09T05:35:27.183Z] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-01-09T05:35:27.183Z]     from util.common import log
[2021-01-09T05:35:27.183Z] ImportError: No module named util.common
```

how do I make sure that stage fails for the case above where python fails?

Answer (score 0):

The `sh script: '''...'''` command will throw/fail your pipeline if the sh script returns a non-zero exit status.
You used `set -ex` so that should make it fail with the first error.
Can you modify your script to show the exit status from python command ?